# Variable shift in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[3,5,3,4,2,3,2,3,4,3,2,2,2,3],
                   'B':[10,20,30,40,20,30,40,10,20,30,15,60,20,15]})

    A   B
0   3  10
1   5  20
2   3  30
3   4  40
4   2  20
5   3  30
6   2  40
7   3  10
8   4  20
9   3  30
10  2  15
11  2  60
12  2  20
13  3  15
```

I'd like to append a `C` column, containing rolling average of `B` (rolling period = `A`).

For example, the `C` value at `row index(2)` should be `df.B.rolling(3).mean() = mean(10,20,30)`, and the `C` value at `row index(4)` should be `df.B.rolling(2).mean() = mean(40,20)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably stupid slow... but this get's it done

```
def crazy_apply(row):
    p = df.index.get_loc(row.name)
    a = row.A
    return df.B.iloc[p-a+1:p+1].mean()

df.apply(crazy_apply, 1)

0           NaN
1           NaN
2     20.000000
3     25.000000
4     30.000000
5     30.000000
6     35.000000
7     26.666667
8     25.000000
9     20.000000
10    22.500000
11    37.500000
12    40.000000
13    31.666667
dtype: float64
```

***explanation***
`apply` iterates through each column or each row.  We iterate through each row because we used the parameter `axis=1` (see `1` as the second argument in the call to `apply`).  So every iteration of `apply` passes the a pandas series object that represents the current row.  the current index value is in the `name` attribute of the row.  The index of the row object is the same as the columns of `df`.

So, `df.index.get_loc(row.name)` finds the ordinal position of the current index value held in `row.name`.  `row.A` is the column `A` for that row.